# Convert Character to Integer in Swift

Tags: swift

I am creating an iPhone app and I need to convert a single digit number into an integer.

My code has a variable called char that has a type Character, but I need to be able to do math with it, therefore I think I need to convert it to a string, however I cannot find a way to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check out [ask] for information on how to get the most out of your questions.  In this case, please provide a sample of the code you have tried that hasn't worked so readers know where to start.

Comment: "I need to be able to do math with it, therefore I think I need to convert it to a string" - traditionally, we convert things to numbers to do math with them.

Answer (score 66):

In the latest Swift versions (at least in Swift 5) there is a more straighforward way of converting `Character` instances. `Character` has property `wholeNumberValue` which tries to convert a character to `Int` and returns `nil` if the character does not represent and integer.

```swift
let char: Character = "5"
if let intValue = char.wholeNumberValue {
    print("Value is \(intValue)")
} else {
    print("Not an integer")
}
```

Comment: This is extremely faster than Int(String(char)).

Comment: `wholeNumberValue` is really cool!  However, "④" and "百" would be converted to 4 and 100 separately; do you think it's really what you want?

Answer (score 37):

With a `Character` you can create a `String`. And with a `String` you can create an `Int`.

```
let char: Character = "1"
if let number = Int(String(char)) {
    // use number    
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `String` middleman type conversion isn’t necessary if you use the [`unicodeScalars`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/2906952-unicodescalars) property of Swift 4.0’s `Character` type.

```
let myChar: Character = "3"
myChar.unicodeScalars.first!.value - Unicode.Scalar("0")!.value // 3: UInt32
```

This uses a trick commonly seen in C code of subtracting the value of the `char` `’0’` literal to convert from ascii values to decimal values. See this site for the conversions: https://www.asciitable.com

Also there are some implicit unwraps in my answer. To avoid those, you can validate that you have a decimal digit with `CharacterSet.decimalDigits`, and/or use `guard let`s around the `first` property. You can also subtract 48 directly rather than converting `”0”` through `Unicode.Scalar`.