# Swift --- Convert Char to Int in a for in loop

Tags: swift

I'd like to convert each char in a string for-in loop, but failed


**Here's my code**

```
let stringImported: String = "12345678"
for char in stringImported {
    print(Int(char))
}
```

**Get this error**

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') conform to 'BinaryInteger'
```

Comment: How can a Character be an Int in your view? What Int is `b`, for example, and why? Alternatively, if the goal is to print 1 and then 2 and so on, why convert to Int at all?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Int` initializer that takes a `Character` but `Character` has a property called [`wholeNumberValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127025-wholenumbervalue) which returns an optional `Int`:

```
let stringImported = "12345678"
for char in stringImported {
    print(char.wholeNumberValue ?? "nil")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Int cannot operate over chars, it has to be converted to String. Code snippet change to reflect that.

The cast to`Int` does not guarantee that the conversion will be successful. You need to provide a default value:

```
let stringImported: String = "12345678"
for char in stringImported {
    print("\(Int(String(char)) ?? 0)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Character to String first** and then convert it to Int will success

```swift
let stringImported: String = "12345678"
for char in stringImported {
    print(Int(String(char)))
}
```

also check this stack overflow question and answer.

**Maybe this question is duplicated**

[Convert Character to Integer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781776/convert-character-to-integer-in-swift)